# spark-shell command giving error(windows cmd and cygwin)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cmd, cygwin

Using Windows 10, jdk 16.0.1, scala 2.13.5, spark 3.1.1, hadoop 2.7, the command `spark-shell` gives the following error in cmd.exe:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1095)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1013)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1013)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1030)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @7530ad9c
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
        at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:56)
        ... 13 more
```

Cygwin:

```
D:\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\java -cp "D:\spark/conf\;D:\spark\jars\*" "-Dscala.usejavacp=true" "-Djline.terminal=unix" -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main --name "Spark shell" spark-shell
D:\spark/bin/spark-class: line 96: CMD: bad array subscript
```

**[Edit /]**

I just solved it by using spark 2.4.7 instead and making a separate `hadoop\bin` for winutils. Though I would like to ask why that happened?

Comment: I was facing the same issue. I was using Spark 3.1.1 and was getting the same issue. I changed the version to Spark 2.4.8 and is working fine now.

Comment: @OP can you add your edit as an accepted answer?

Comment: Can we resolve this issue in the recent version of Spark?

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this error. it was a Java version issue. if you see the spark documentation, it doesn't support anything other than java 8 or 11.

please find the link here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/

Try installing Java 8 and then set its respective environment variable. you need not change Hadoop and spark version to 2.7. it works with version 3.2.1 as well.

after you finish setup, restart the cmd prompt and type: spark-shell and the magic happens!!!

Comment: धन्यवाद. java १६ चा बदल करून  java ८ वापरल्याने व्यवस्थित चालले

Comment: downgrade jdk to java8 then restart bash solved this problem!